# My Time program is not correctly outputting the (am/pm)

Tags: c++, class, time

My program compiles and runs fine, with one major exception. The am/pm function is significantly off. To give background details as to what exactly my program does, numbers are inputted into the time() constructors that I have defined. So, if the user enters in 23:12:26:79, it would output the same time as PM. Likewise, if the user enters in 30:00:00:00 into the constructor, the program should roll over so that is is outputted as 6:00:00:00 as there are not 30 hours in a day. The program does that fine, however, it says that the 6:00:00:00 is PM, and not AM as it should be. I am sure it is a simple fix, but I cannot see it. All help is appreciated. I will post my code below for reference.

The comments should be clear enough, but I want to put a disclaimer that the code may not be the most efficient.

First, my definition class.

```
/**  Time.h**/
#ifndef TIME_H_
#define TIME_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
/***  Time class**  The Time class contains time as   hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds (AM/PM).*/

class Time {
    public:
    /** *  Constructor with zero values */
    Time();

    /** *  Constructors with arguments */
    Time(long long time);
    Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milli);

    /** *  Deconstructor */
    virtual ~Time();

    /** *  Return time as   a  long long value representing time in milliseconds */
    long long asLong() const;

    /** *  Provide a  string in the format hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds. *  For example 1:45:30:56 PM */
    std::string toString() const;

    /** *  Output the time to   an   output stream as hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds AM/PM */
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const Time&);

    // Output a Time to an output stream

/** *  Declare ordering relationships */
    friend bool operator <(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator >(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator ==(const Time &a, const Time &b);

    /** *  Declare addition and subtraction */
     Time operator +(const Time&);
     friend Time operator -(const Time&, const Time&);
private:
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int millis;
};

#endif /*   TIME_H_ */
```

Secondly, my source.

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Defualt Constructor
Time::Time() {
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    millis = 0;
}

// Constructors with arguments

Time::Time(long long timeValue) {

    long long tempValue = timeValue;
    millis = tempValue % 1000;
    tempValue /= 1000;
    seconds = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    minutes = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    hours = tempValue;
}

Time::Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis) {

        int add_seconds = millis / 1000;
        millis -= add_seconds * 1000;
        seconds += add_seconds;

        int add_minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds -= add_minutes * 60;
        minutes += add_minutes;

        int add_hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes -= add_hours * 60;
        hours += add_hours;

        this->hours = hours;
        this->minutes = minutes;
        this->seconds = seconds;
        this->millis = millis;

}

// Destructor
Time::~Time() {

}

// Return time in term of milliseconds.

long long Time::asLong() const {
    long long timeValue = (long long) hours;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 60) + minutes;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 60) + seconds;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 1000) + millis;
    return timeValue;

}

// Formatting

std::string Time::toString() const {
    ostringstream  v1;
    string ph;

      /*if (hours <= 12)
           ph = "am";
       else
           ph = "pm";

       v1 << hours % 24 << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << millis << ph;

       return v1.str();*/
    if(hours < 12)
            ph = "am";
        else if (hours == 12 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && millis == 0)
            ph = "am";
        else
            ph = "pm";

        v1 << hours % 24 << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << millis << " " << ph;

        return v1.str();




}

// Time to Output Stream
ostream& operator <<(ostream& a, const Time& b)
{
    return a << b.toString();
}

// Ordering Relationships
bool operator <(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    return t1.asLong() < t2.asLong();
}

bool operator >(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    return t1.asLong() > t2.asLong();
}
bool operator ==(const Time &a, const Time &b)
{
    return a.asLong() == b.asLong();
}

Time Time::operator +(const Time& rhs)
{
    return Time(this->asLong() + rhs.asLong()); //still need to account for time wrapping
}

Time operator -(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    a = t1.hours-t2.hours;
    b = t1.minutes-t2.minutes;
    c = t1.seconds-t2.seconds;
    d = t1.millis - t2.millis;
    if (d < 0)
    {
        c = c -1;
        d = d + 1000;
    }
    if (c < 0)
    {
        b = b - 1;
        c = c + 60;
    }
    if (b < 0)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        b = b - 60;
    }
    if (a < 24)
    {
        a = a + 24;
    }

    return Time(a,b,c,d);
}
```

And lastly, my main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Tests for user-defined methods.
        Time zeroTime;
        Time oneTime(1L);
        Time twoTime(4,30,26,72); //Normal
        Time threeTime(24,00,00,00); //Overloaded Hour
        Time fourTime(22,60,00,00); // Overloaded Minutes
        Time fiveTime(22,58,60,00);  // Overloaded Seconds
        Time sixTime(17,28,13,1001); // Overloaded Millis
        Time sevenTime(8,45,900,1240); //Double Overloaded

        cout << zeroTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << oneTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << twoTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << zeroTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << oneTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << twoTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << threeTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << fourTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << fiveTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << sixTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << sevenTime.toString() <<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: First adjust `hours` modulo 24, and then figure out am vs pm. Also, you print, say, `13 pm` and not `1 pm` as is the convention.

Comment: Just from a quick look, five bucks says you can reproduce the error with significantly less code. Not only does this make the question and its answers easier to follow for future askers of similar questions, but reducing a problem to the bare essentials required to produce the problem very often reveals the problem in all its dark glory.

Comment: @user4581301 Just to clarify, do you mean only post the essential part of my program that relates to my problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I agree that 13 pm is a bit odd, but this assignment I am doing tells me to keep everything in terms of the 24 hour clock, which is why I am using %24

Comment: If you say so. The point, is, you compare `30` to `12`, not `30 % 24`, when computing am vs pm.

Comment: No. I mean create a program that only exercises the your logic for determining AM and PM. Once you have that, you can experiment with it in isolation. Plus the smaller code size gives bugs and other unexpected nasties less place to hide. As an added bonus, the act of deciding whether or not you need a line of code forces you to consider what it is and does and how is contributes to the program. Often this results in "D'OH!" and fixing the code without going any further.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik With what line are you referring to? Where am I comparing 30 to 12?  Is it the (If hours <12)?

Comment: @user4581301 That is a good suggestion. I will create a code sample program with just that feature and see if I can debug my error

Comment: After `hours += add_hours` you need to put `hours %= 24`, that is the suggestion.

Comment: He was referring to your conditional.  Following the above suggestions, your conditional would correctly check if 6 <12, whereas right now based on your current code it is comparing if 30<12...that's why you get pm.

Answer (score 0):

In your `toString()` function, you print "pm" if the hour is greater than 12:00:00. But nowhere in your code do you account for hours greater than 24. There is no place in the code where you do, say `hours = hours % 24`, except in the print line, which doesn't affect anything else. So any hour over 12 will cause the program to print "pm".